# I can't get my WIreguard tunnel to complete a handshake

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ipsec, wireguard

I'm trying to setup a point-to-site wireguard tunnel between two different points on two seperate networks, but have setup similar tunnels setup in similar situations so I don't believe it has anything to do with the infrastructure between my tunnel's endpoints.

On one side I have a vm Windows Client with the following configuration

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = iOoRnq+ngYGZFGpSqnRGgBsUvh9AVtWAXZGEw2Ir1FI=
Address = 10.1.3.11/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = +IrgeRu8nRBMWZrR8Grrxfe6mhSBUihyKKeKsoPJCGM=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 172.16.2.53:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 15
```

On the other side is a vm Ubuntu Server (acting as a router) with the following configuration

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = +PYij5eViZfalUxsxR8XHf4xX8Jwiap7SyGn/Ok992k=[Interface]
PrivateKey = +PYij5eViZfalUxsxR8XHf4xX8Jwiap7SyGn/Ok992k=
Address = 10.1.3.10/32
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens37 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens37 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = T54bRdcw6J5QqOm1VsIjX0bH9GJvhreZQTwzBFCEgnc=
AllowedIPs = 10.1.3.11/32
~
```

I know both ends are talking to each other because I can see the transfer stats on the windows side showing data being recieved and sent.

In the logs on the windows client, I have this:

```
2022-05-17 20:10:33.330829: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Peer 1 created
2022-05-17 20:10:33.334575: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Monitoring MTU of default v6 routes
2022-05-17 20:10:33.332262: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:10:33.332958: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:10:33.334575: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Interface up
2022-05-17 20:10:33.345348: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Setting device v6 addresses
2022-05-17 20:10:33.350652: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Receiving handshake response from peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:10:33.350652: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Keypair 1 created for peer 1
2022-05-17 20:10:33.361014: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Monitoring MTU of default v4 routes
2022-05-17 20:10:33.361014: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Setting device v4 addresses
2022-05-17 20:10:33.403831: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Startup complete
2022-05-17 20:10:48.459601: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Retrying handshake with peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820) because we stopped hearing back after 15 seconds
2022-05-17 20:10:48.459601: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:10:50.275215: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Receiving keepalive packet from peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:10:53.585242: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Handshake for peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
2022-05-17 20:10:53.585242: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:10:56.294435: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Receiving handshake response from peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:10:56.294435: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Keypair 2 created for peer 1
2022-05-17 20:10:56.294435: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:12.348180: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Retrying handshake with peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820) because we stopped hearing back after 15 seconds
2022-05-17 20:11:12.348180: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:13.373244: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Receiving handshake initiation from peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:13.373244: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending handshake response to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:13.382240: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Keypair 1 destroyed for peer 1
2022-05-17 20:11:13.382240: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Keypair 3 created for peer 1
2022-05-17 20:11:13.384241: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Invalid handshake response from 172.16.2.53:51820
2022-05-17 20:11:17.360089: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Handshake for peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
2022-05-17 20:11:18.524497: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Receiving handshake initiation from peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:18.524497: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending handshake response to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:18.528377: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Keypair 3 destroyed for peer 1
2022-05-17 20:11:18.528377: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Keypair 4 created for peer 1
2022-05-17 20:11:18.530502: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Receiving keepalive packet from peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:41.490680: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Retrying handshake with peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820) because we stopped hearing back after 15 seconds
2022-05-17 20:11:41.491688: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:43.383896: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Receiving handshake initiation from peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:43.383896: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Sending handshake response to peer 1 (172.16.2.53:51820)
2022-05-17 20:11:43.387327: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Keypair 2 destroyed for peer 1
2022-05-17 20:11:43.387327: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Keypair 5 created for peer 1
2022-05-17 20:11:57.082780: [TUN] [LAN-Router] Shutting down
2022-05-17 20:11:57.097321: [MGR] [LAN-Router] Tunnel service tracker finished
```

Both sides seem to be talking to each other but are not agree on something or maybe the same kind of packet is getting lost. I turned off the firewall on the ubuntu server router to make sure that wasn't my problem. I've tried googling these irregular lines in the logs but the best solution I find is to retry making keys which I've done several times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem, wireguard setup works great from my iPhone but the same config doesn't work with windows, fails at handshake. Seems to be an windows issue.